# In which html tags could be placed link

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to extract all links from given url using `simple_html_dom library` like this:

```
foreach($content->find('a') as $element) {
    if($element->href) {            
        array_push($links, $element->href); 
    }
}
```

My question is: In which html tags (usually) could some `href`,`src` or other link attributtes be placed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have an array, then, what do you need to do with it ? can you show the array output and what is expected after ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `href` attribute is valid for `a`, `area`, `base` and `link`.
an `src` attribute is valid for `audio`, `embed`, `iframe`, `img`, `input`, `script`, `source`, `track` and `video`.

However, isn't it easier to just search for elements with this attribute rather than filter on the tagname?

Comment: Thanks for reply. And what about other attribute where some link could be placed? Like `action` in tag `form`.